# oracle 9i does not support aq subscribers?

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to make oracle aq queue subscriber (Oracle9i Enterprise Edition Release 9.2.0.8.0 - 64bit Production). Script

```
DECLARE
   subs sys.aq$_agent;
BEGIN
   subs :=  sys.aq$_agent('Subscriber_1', NULL, NULL);
   DBMS_AQADM.ADD_SUBSCRIBER(
      queue_name  =>  'queue1',
      subscriber  =>  subs);
END;
```

works well, but than I'm trying to see subscribers for this queue (in SQL developer), I see message:

> Not currently available for this DB Version.

And than I'm trying to delete this user, I have message than such user is not subscribed to the corresponding queue.

How can I check if my Oracle 9 supports aq subscribers or enable this support?

UPDATE:

All works fine, just this version of SQL Developer does not support this feature for Oracle 9

Comment: What edition of the database (Enterprise, etc) are you running?

Comment: Oracle 9i has long been deprecated. You should upgrade to a supported version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not look at the [documentation](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db92/homepage)?

The object [`aq$_agent`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96587/qbascmpt.htm#77328) exists in 9i as does the package [`dbms_aqadm`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96612/d_aqadm.htm#ARPLS005). The first link in the latter leads to the [Oracle9i Application Developer's Guide - Advanced Queuing](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96587/toc.htm).

This is not a typical Oracle error message (Googling it returns only this question). How are you `trying to see subscribers for this queue`? Are you querying the actual tables or using an inbuilt SQL Developer implementation?

Comment: in sql developer in left menu connection has queues node; and queue description looks like a table descriptin (with details, sql, schedules, subscribers links). After entering subscribes view I see some kind of table editor with only one cell, where displayed "Not currently available for this DB Version."

Comment: I wouldn't bother trying to use SQL Developer to administer a 9i database, there a number of places where its just going to get things wrong.

Comment: @rdo, you're probably using the wrong version of SQL Developer for a 9i database. Just query the tables directly.